# array_slice function with a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
foreach ($r['result']['mounts']['collected'] as $item) echo '

                        <li class="span3 clearfix" data-tag=', $item['qualityId'], '>
                                <a
                                        href="//de.wowhead.com/item=', $item['itemId'], '"
                                        class="', $item['qualityId'], '"
                                >
                                        <img
                                                src="http://wow.zamimg.com/images/wow/icons/large/', $item['icon'], '.jpg"
                                                alt="', htmlspecialchars($item['name']), '"
                                        >
                        </li>';

echo '
```

The array is large and has over 500 (numeric) keys. I just want that the first 50 keys gets loaded. 
Is it possible with the array_slice() function? But here is the problem I don´t know to handle it with a foreach loop.

Comment: Do you mean that there're over 500 items?

Comment: How do you receive this data, if from DB you can just limit query to 50. If you want use array slice you can do it  array_slice($r['result']['mounts']['collected'], 0 , 50);

Comment: The array_slice funtion seems to be right. How do I echo it out? array_slice($r['result']['mounts']['collected'], 0 , 50 as $item) echo '   - doesn´t work

Comment: `foreach (array_slice($r['result']['mounts']['collected'], 0, 50) as $item) echo` ...

Comment: Thank you  trincot. Thats exactly what i´ve searched.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is not clear enough, wether your `result` array is large or any of its sub arrays, at this time, i think a `foreach` loop is not required.
If your `$result` array is large, you can slice it like this:

```
$firstFiftyItems = array_slice($result, 0, 50);
```

I will update this answer as soon as you comment on it.

Comment: Yeah the result array has over 500 keys. I juse use   foreach (array_slice($r['result']['mounts']['collected'], 0, 50) as $item) echo now. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) for array_slice().

You can try something like this (just adding as hint.. :) )

```
//lets say this is your collection
$arr = ["a"=>"a","b"=>"b","c"=>"c","d"=>"d","e"=>"e","f"=>"f","g"=>"g"]; 
// set counter you want to iterate over.
$j =0;
$step = 3; // set the step value (in your case it will 50.) 
for($i = 0 ;$i<3;$i++)
{
 $b = array_slice($arr,$j,$step);
 $j = $j+$step; // increment counter by to step position. 
 print_r($b); // this is the collection you want. save it or use directly     
}
```